# Unable to send Firebase QueryDocumentSnapshot over API Call

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I'm currently making my first network call in a paginated series of calls on the server side. Prior to doing this I was making all of the calls client side and stored the last document in the collection call as an offset.

The offset was then sent as a .startAfter call for the same collection. The offset document looked like this:

```
exists: (...)
id: (...)
metadata: (...)
ref: (...)
_document: Document {key: DocumentKey, version: SnapshotVersion, data: ObjectValue, proto: {…}, hasLocalMutations: false, …}
_firestore: Firestore {_queue: AsyncQueue, INTERNAL: {…}, _config: FirestoreConfig, _databaseId: DatabaseId, _dataConverter: UserDataConverter, …}
_fromCache: false
_hasPendingWrites: false
_key: DocumentKey {path: ResourcePath}
__proto__: DocumentSnapshot
```

When I make the call on the server I'm currently able to see the document looks the same, but when I send it over the network it seems to be stripped or at least looks very different by the time it's sent over JSON and parsed back.

Sent like this:

```
res.json(offset)
```

then parsed like this:

```
feedData = await dataWithOffset.json();
```

After the parsing it looks like this:

```
{ _ref:
   { _firestore:
      { _settings: [Object],
        _settingsFrozen: true,
        _serializer: [Object],
        _projectId: '***-prod',
        _lastSuccessfulRequest: 1566308918946,
        _preferTransactions: false,
        _clientPool: [Object] },
     _path:
      { segments: [Array],
        projectId: '***-prod',
        databaseId: '(default)' } },
  _fieldsProto:
   { lastModified: { timestampValue: [Object], valueType: 'timestampValue' },
     ...,
  _serializer: { timestampsInSnapshots: true },
  _readTime: { _seconds: 1566308918, _nanoseconds: 909566000 },
  _createTime: { _seconds: 1565994031, _nanoseconds: 304997000 },
  _updateTime: { _seconds: 1565994031, _nanoseconds: 304997000 } }
```

Any idea why it is losing its shape and what I can do to fix it so it returns to working as a proper offset? Should I not be converting to JSON and back, as that may strip some important things?

Answer (score -1):

### Solution (tested)

So I went ahead and made a sandbox to test the implementation, and like I mentioned in the comments `.startAfter` expects a `DocumentSnapshot` not a `DocumentReference`

Given that I created a collection named `cars` with 4 records like this:

```
 [
        {
            "name": "car 1",
            "hp": 5
        },
        {
            "name": "car 2",
            "hp": 10
        },
        {
            "name": "car 2.5",
            "hp": 10
        },
        {
            "name": "car 3",
            "hp": 15
        }
    ]
```

Then I configured an express endpoint:

```
router.get('/cars/:lastDocId', (req, res) => {
    const query = db.collection('cars')
        .orderBy('hp')
        .limit(2);

    const handleQueryRes = (snap) => {
        return res.send({
            docs: snap.docs.map(doc => doc.data()),
            last: snap.docs.length > 0 ? snap.docs[snap.docs.length - 1].id : null
        });
    }
    if(req.params.lastDocId != -1) {
        // this makes an "auxiliar" read from the DB to transform the given ID in a DocumentSnapshot needed for startAfter
        return db.collection('cars').doc(req.params.lastDocId).get().then(snap => {
            return query.startAfter(snap).get();
        }).then(handleQueryRes).catch(console.log);
    } else {
        return query.get().then(handleQueryRes).catch(console.log);
    }

});
```

The path parameter `lastDocId` is either `-1` for first page or the last document fetched in the previous page

When I make a GET request to `/cars/-1` it returns this:

```
{
    "docs": [
        {
            "hp": 5,
            "name": "car 1"
        },
        {
            "name": "car 2",
            "hp": 10
        }
    ],
    "last": "9sRdLOvV8REwEpHDjEw7"
}
```

Now if I grab the `last` prop in the response and use it in my next GET like so `/cars/9sRdLOvV8REwEpHDjEw7` I get my next 2 cars:

```
{
    "docs": [
        {
            "name": "car 2.5",
            "hp": 10
        },
        {
            "name": "car 3",
            "hp": 15
        }
    ],
    "last": "tZPF7Wav7jZuchoCp6zM"
}
```

Even though I only have 4 records and the second request should be the last the function does not know the length of the collection so it returns another `last` ID

If you make the last request `/cars/tZPF7Wav7jZuchoCp6zM` it returns:

```
{
    "docs": [],
    "last": null
}
```

Thus giving indication that is the last page.

I'm not too fond of having to read the document again to transform it into a `DocumentSnapshot` but I guess that's a firebase limitation

Hope it helped

---

#### Answer with steps

When converting to JSON and back you lose the DocumentReference prototype

The solution to pass that type of data through network requests is:

- Client sends a plain-text `ref` to your endpoint ( or doesn't for first page)
- Have the server side code [re-create the DocumentReference with the received `ref`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore.html#doc)
- Use the re-created DocumentReference to paginate query
- Return from server the requested page's documents alongside with a plain-text `ref`to get the next page

---

#### Initial answer (obsolete) but for future reference

You need to send `offset.data()` instead of sending `offset` alltogether

One is the document's data (probably what you're after) the other is a DocumentReference which has methods that cannot be represented in JSON.

If you need anything else from the document (like it's id or reference) you're better off building a new object:

```
res.json({
   data: offset.data(),
   ref: offset.ref,
   id: offset.id
});
```

Comment: According to the documentation (and in comparison to a previously working solution), the snapshot is what is expected here. Once it's transformed into data, ref, and ID, it seems it's no longer a snapshot. What does the startAfter truly expect if it's not the original format? Docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#use_a_document_snapshot_to_define_the_query_cursor

Comment: If you are converting to JSON you are losing the DocumentReference prototype, if you are making requests that need a DocumentReference use the `ref` property and re-create the DocumentReference like so: `firestore().doc(ref)`

Comment: Appreciate the update, but I don't think you can re-create a document reference like that

Comment: You can, you probably need it's full path collection and all. If you can share some server side code I may be able to help you further

Comment: it's the full collection path with id instead of ref in .doc(). It doesn't seem like references work for startAfter though. There's also no documentation to support it should. Seems snapshots are what it expects, so this won't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I dug a little deeper into firestore reference docs, aparently `startAfter` requires a DocumentSnapshot and not a DocumentReference, it's unclear on wether you can achieve the same result if you query the individual document and use it's snapshot from an auxiliar query and pass it onto `startAfter` method.
I'm going to do some tests will get back to this